# Facebook posts by others don't appear on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

I want posts by others as well as posts by page to appear on the page's timeline. I have enabled it in manage permissions but it will not work.

Notably, at the top of the page's timeline "Highlights" appears in the center and the dropdown gives the options Posts by Page and Post by Others. No posts by others appear on the timeline, only in the upper right box.

(Clicking on them there does and selecting Allow on Page does not move them to timeline either.) I'm starting to think I'm the only one with this problem.

Comment: You are not the only one with this problem. For me, this usually happens when selecting "Allowed on Page" for multiple photos posted by others. Very often, one or more of these photos will *not* make it to the page, but the exact "logic" behind exactly which ones do or do not is unclear to me.  Choosing "Highlighted on Page" will *always* causes these posts to show up on the page, but usually that is not what I want.  I want them to show up, but not highlighted.

Comment: [Officially, it should always work as shown in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-j1SYX0O_w]

Answer (score 1):

The only way to display a post by others (respectively page) on the timeline default view is to:

- Go to the "Posts by Others" (respectively "Post by Page") view

[image]

- Highlight the post

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your followers can see posts by others (rather than posts by page) by clicking on them within the 'recent posts by others' box (viewable under 'highlights'), or by clicking on 'posts by others' as suggested above.

However, if you click on an individual post by another person and choose 'share on timeline', this should mean that the post appears under the 'Posts by Page' view.